# Undefined symbols error from static framework

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm linking against a static framework in my Xcode project, but despite setting everything up right the linker keeps failing with 'Undefined symbols for...':

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've had problems with this in the past, all resolved by making sure the library is set up to link, however I can't seem to see where the problem would be in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is probably because your lib is not being built agains armv7s.
Go to the build settings of your static lib and find the flag "Build Active Architecture Only". Set that to "NO". After that, clean your project and build again (make sure that armv7s is listed in the "Valid Architectures").

Answer (score 0):

do you use iphone5 to build the application?
it need the armv7s compile ,so if you have the source code ,you need to rebuild the code to be a new framework